# CSS Visibility Animation Not working

Tags: html, animation, css

I want to do a keyframe based animation on the the visibility CSS property. I initially tried it on 'display' but found that animation on 'display' is not supported but 'visibility' is. The idea is to make visibility of rectangle keep toggling. I do not want to use jquery and want to implement whole of it in CSS. Following is my code but it does not give the expected result of the rectangle remaining hidden till the 5th second, appearing and then again disappearing at the end of animation

```
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
     #layer1 {            
                -moz-animation-duration: 10s;                
        -moz-animation-name: toggle;
     }

     @-moz-keyframes toggle {
             from {
                visibility:hidden;
             }

         50% {
                    visibility:visible;
             }

         to {
         visibility:hidden;
          }
   }

  </style>

  <script type="application/javascript">
      window.onload = function()              
      {
           var c = document.getElementById('layer1');
           var ctxt = c.getContext('2d');
           ctxt.fillStyle = 'red';
           ctxt.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
           ctxt.fillStyle = 'green';
           ctxt.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
      }

  </script>
```

```
  <body>

        <canvas id="layer1" width="200" height="200" >         
   </canvas>

  </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

A CSS transition or animation  on the visibility property keeps the element visible
  for the duration of the transition and then abruptly applies the new value.
  (assuming the current spec and as long as no special timing function is used.)
  Transitions/Animations on visibility do not show a gradually changing
  visual effect, however as I read the question the idea is indeed
  to keep the element hidden till the 5th second.

Your CSS animation specifies a first transition from 0% to 50% 
  turning from hidden to visible which shows the element according
  to the rule above and then you specify a transition from 50% to
  100% from visible to hidden, which also shows the element while 
  playing. So the element it permanently visible.

By specifying

```
@keyframes toggle {
         from {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     50% {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     to {
            visibility:visible;
      }
 }
```

the element will stay hidden until 50% and then abruptly appear.
  To hide it at the end, you need to add visibility:hidden to
  the main style sheet rule not to the keyframes.
  Also see my blog post on CSS transition visibility
http://www.taccgl.org/blog/css-transition-visibility.html#Appearance_CSS_Visibility

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 13):

Visibility (and display) property can't be animated. An element is either visible or not. Try the `opacity` property instead:

```
@-moz-keyframes toggle {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }

    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties- visibility is an animatable property. Even the Safari documentation mentions that visibility can be animated http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transitions/Transitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH4-SW1. I even saw a BUG fix for Mozilla in 2009 that fixes the animation on visibility

Comment: visibility can be animated, right. But not to create a visual effect. You have to use it with "true" animatable properties. When and how to use visibility as an animation property, you can be see @ http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337