# CSS Animate opacity, then set visibility to hidden?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an area with lots of objects, including buttons etc that can be clicked.

Animating opacity is working great, but I have found that buttons not visible are still in the stack on the canvas and therefore still clickable. I'd like to run an opacity animation and then set the item to visibility hidden once it's done...is this possible?

My attempt yields an animation that fades in, but then suddenly drops off the page, before a fade out animation can be run.

I'm basically trying to avoid the interference of other elements on the canvas, but still keep them there.

```
.item { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
/* when a class gets added, it animates */
.animate .item {

    animation: fadeIn 2s 1s 1 normal forwards ease-out,
        fadeOut 2s 3s 1 normal forwards ease-out;

}

@keyframes fadeOut {

    1% { opacity: 1; }
    99% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }

}

@keyframes fadeIn {

    1% { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
    2% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }

}
```

I get glitchy behaviour, in that the item disappears before being fully faded out, or perhaps when the fade out begins.

Any solutions?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Does `display: none;` work for you? Instead of `visibility: hidden;` ?

Comment: I'd like the object to maintain its flow and display would take it out of the flow.

Comment: `*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;`

Comment: In short: visibility and display properties can't be animated.

Comment: No, but they can be transitioned(ish). Don't know if this will help: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: You have to use `@-webkit-keyframes` to ensure support in Webkit browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Visibility Animation Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857982/css-visibility-animation-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is just that you are omiting the visibility property in some keyframes.

It is always a good idea to state all the properties being animated in all the keyframes

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    1% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
    2% { opacity: 0; visibility: visible;}
    100% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible;}
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    1% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible;}
    99% { opacity: 0; visibility: visible;}
    100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8QnS/1/)